# Modifying the value of structs inside an array of structs

Tags: arrays, swift, constants, swift5

I have a struct like this

```
struct MyStruct {
  var name : String?
  var address : String?
  var affiliated : Bool?
}
```

and then an array of `MyStruct`

```
var myArray : [MyStruct]? ...
```

As soon as I create an array of `MyStruct` every element inside that array is non-mutating, right?

The problem is that at some point I have to scan that array and update a field of all elements, like updating `affiliated` for every element of  `myArray` and this update is asynchronous.

This is my problem. All elements inside `myArray` are not mutating.

The way I would solve that was by recreating every `MyStruct` element with the new value for `affiliated`, recreating `myArray` and replacing the old array with this new one.

It seems a dumb method, a waste of time and effort.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As soon as I create an array of MyStruct every element inside that array is non-mutating, right?

Not necessarily. But as arrays are value types you have to update an element of the array directly in the array for example

```
var myArray = [MyStruct(name: "Foo", address: nil, affiliated: false), MyStruct(name: "Bar", address: nil, affiliated: false)]

myArray[1].affiliated = true
print(myArray)
```

Comment: Yep. Subscripts are Swift's way to encode l-values (lots of info on this from the C++ world).